# Variables over ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

I am writing a script in bash which needs to do things like:

```
ssh -q 192.168.0.123 echo $FOO $BAR
```

My questions are in fact two:

- How do I pass a local variable from the machine that is invoking it (`$FOO`)?
- How do I specify a remote variable (`$BAR`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use "$localvar" around local variables and '$remotevar' around remote ones, so that your local shell interpret ("$localvar") or does not interpret ('$remotevar') the variable accordingly.

so

```
ssh -q 127.0.0.123 echo "$FOO" '$BAR'
```

(you do know that 127.0.0.0/8 is your local machine, heh? ^^)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The example IP I gave was complete bogus, (lazy of me). Furthermore, as I just found out, if you do `ssh -q 127.0.0.123 echo $FOO \$BAR`, it also has the same effect, apparently.

Comment: @carlspring: no, not lazy, probably wise ^^ not giving info about your local/remote networks is Good. I just wanted to have an amusing last sentence ^^